# I am a seven letter word- who am I?

Tags: riddle

I am a Seven Letter word.
I like Mornings
If you remove my first letter you can drink me.
If you remove my first and second letters, you may not like me
If you remove my last letter, you will see me on television.
Who am I?

Comment: Please give me an answer

Comment: Hi theseeker, and welcome to Puzzling - when you say 'Please give me an answer', does this mean you don't know the correct answer and want us to help you? If so, please tell us where you found this puzzle, so we can credit the original creator and make sure it's not from an ongoing contest (which we're not allowed to help with...). Thanks :)

Answer (score 5):

I've been sorting/filtering 466550 words for the past 4 hours and found 143 which forms real words from condition and I selected one that mostly matches this riddle:

> changer: usually in the morning
>  hanger: is a kind of cocktail
>  anger: nobody likes
>  change: news on TV is always changing

Answer (score 0):

You are

> DRIVERS

Because:

> Drivers like mornings
>     you can drink from RIVERS
>     IVERS are French boys whose name means ″yew, bow army″. One might not like them.
>     DRIVER can be seen on TV often.

Comment: Removing the last letter leaves DRIVER, not DRIVE.

Answer (score 0):

Answer:

> Ecoffee

I like mornings.

> Ecoffee- is a cup used for drinking coffee, we need it in the morning

If you remove my first letter you can drink me.

> Coffee - We drink coffee

If you remove my first and second letters, you may not like me.

> Offee: It is hurting

If you remove my last letter, you will see me on television.

> Ecoffe-It is the news about surrounding.  We shall come to know about the things happening in our surrounding through television.